# I have "El Capitan". I can not upgrade Sierra

Tags: mac

I have "El Capitan". I can not update to Sierra.
The error is:

"We could not complete your purchase"."Could not connect to the server"

Comment: Does your hardware satisfy the requirements for Sierra?  Even though this sounds like a communication problem with Apple's servers, I have to ask you to verify, if your hardware satisfies the requirements for Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's download servers regularly get swamped during OS and OS dot releases and fail if you try to do the upgrade/install via App Store.

Instead, choose the "download" option and hopefully, you'll get all the bits and be able to install locally.  Once successfully downloaded, the installer will be in your Applications folder and called "Install macOS Sierra."  Just double-click on it to launch it and start the upgrade.